# String mismatch on test in django model test

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

Been banging my head against a wall for two days trying to figure out why my test is not passing.  I've wrapped them in str().  Multiline string.  Just can't get this to pass.  What am I missing here.  Please help.

This is my first post.  So if I left anything out in my post that I could do better please let me know.

Here is my model

```
class MemberAddress(models.Model):
    address_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='Home')
    address_line_one = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address_line_two = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    UserProfile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['address_type',
                       'address_line_one',
                       'city',
                       'state',
                       'zipcode'
                       ]

    def __str__(self):
        address = self.address_line_one + '\n'
        if (self.address_line_two is not None):
            address += self.address_line_two + '\n'
        address += self.city + ' ' + self.state + ' ' + self.zipcode
        return address
```

Here is my test:

```
def test_member_address_is_created(self):
    faker = Faker('en_US')
    test_address = MemberAddress(
        address_type='Home',
        address_line_one=faker.street_address(),
        address_line_two=faker.secondary_address(),
        city=faker.city(),
        state=faker.state(),
        zipcode=faker.zipcode(),
        UserProfile=self.user
    )
    test_address.save()
    queried_address = MemberAddress.objects.get(id=1)

    object_string_test = '{}{}{}{}{} {} {}'.format(
        test_address.address_line_one, '\n',
        test_address.address_line_two, '\n',
        test_address.city, test_address.state, test_address.zipcode)

    self.assertEqual(test_address.address_type,
                     queried_address.address_type)
    self.assertEqual(test_address.address_line_one,
                     queried_address.address_line_one)
    self.assertEqual(test_address.address_line_two,
                     queried_address.address_line_two)
    self.assertEqual(test_address.city,
                     queried_address.city)
    self.assertEqual(test_address.state,
                     queried_address.state)
    self.assertEqual(test_address.state,
                     queried_address.state)
    self.assertEqual(test_address.zipcode,
                     queried_address.zipcode)
    self.assertEqual(test_address.UserProfile,
                     queried_address.UserProfile)
    self.assertEqual(object_string_test, test_address) #  <---- Failing Test ----<<<
```

Here is my error:

```
python manage.py test   
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
.....F..
======================================================================
FAIL: test_member_address_is_created (cms.tests.test_models.ModelTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bhwood/code/glidden_app/cms/tests/test_models.py", line 115, in test_member_address_is_created
    self.assertEqual(object_string_test, test_address)
AssertionError: '88043 Jason Place\nSuite 703\nWest Markmouth West Virginia 90857' != <MemberAddress: 88043 Jason Place
Suite 703
West Markmouth West Virginia 90857>

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 8 tests in 2.404s

FAILED (failures=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Comment: You need to use `str(test_address)` if you want to test `__str()__`, otherwise you will get the result of `__repr()__`. If you use that it is just a matter of getting the string right.

Comment: That was it!  Thank you! @MrBeanBremen Passed immediately.